# change .aspx to other like .abcd with rewriteModule

Tags: asp.net

i want to change .aspx to like .abcd with rewriteModule in asp.net and iis7?

therefore when user typed home/default.aspx must be redirect to home/default.abcd

please help me

excuse for my weakly english writing

thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love rewrite urls is more secure by example i rename all my .aspx to .do

Read this article by Microsoft [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) and read [Scott Gu Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)